# Select all children of a node using DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have this XML code:

```
<root>
  <node>
    </first_child>
    </second_child>
    </third_child>
  </node>
</root>
```

I need to take all children nodes one by one and save like three Node variable using DOM.

If I use

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("node");
```

I take this "node" with all the children, while I need only "first_child, second_child and third_child"

How to obtain this?

Comment: Remember that DOM library often returns type of `Node`, but `Node` is everything, including `Document`. So you can locate `Node` then cast it appropriate type (like `Element`) and then work with it's methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Element el = (Element)(doc.getElementsByTagName("node").item(0));
NodeList children = el.getChildNodes();

for (int i=0; i<children.getLength(); i++) {
  System.out.println(children.item(0).getNodeValue());
}
```

Comment: You should cast to (Element) explicitly, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
Element el;
el = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("node").item(0);
el.getChildNodes();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the children in this way.

```
var children = document.getElementById('node').getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Comment: None of his nodes has an `id` attribute, so `getElementById()` won't work.